# Summarizing a table in sql server by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 20 columns in which one column is a transaction date and one is a sales amount column. I want to pull all the columns and group it by transaction date. But I get a error if I don't mention all the columns in group by. Any suggestions.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: This won't work unless all the values in each row are the same. Otherwise, which row's data would you get? This is why you get the error you are getting.

Comment: please explain with some sample data and show expected output ..DDL would be much helpfull .you can look at here to ask question and get faster responses and even upvotes,even though question is basic  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I would not be able to provide a sample file as it contains office information. My actual file contains 85 columns and when I group by all of these it takes ages to execute the query. I want to reduce the row size as my current table has 20 lakh rows and summarizing at transaction date so that the number of rows reduces. I want to group multiple same type of transaction by same person on same date and summarize.

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns. You need to provide some aggregate function to use it with group by. E.g:

```
SELECT transaction_date, COUNT(sales_amount) as AmountCount
FROM table_name
GROUP BY transaction_date
```

Comment: You don't *need* to, but its unusual not to. What you do *need* is a table name.

Comment: sorry forgot about the table name as it is not mentioned in the question

Comment: I need all the columns to populate

Comment: you can add any column you want after the `select` statement. where is the problem? why don't you provide some sample data with desired output for us?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
order by transaction_date ASC
```

note:
This will selects your 20 column from table ordered by Transaction date and change ASC or DESC as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

When using Aggregate functions in SQL you need to use the group by statement by non-aggregate functions.

Example:

```
Select a.transactiondate,
       a.vehicles,
       a.market,
       a.city,
       sum(a.quantity) as Quantity
from table_name a
group by a.transactiondate,
       a.vehicles,
       a.market,
       a.city
```

**Sum** being your aggregate function so you will not include in your **group by**. Even if you want to just **group by** date, you will need any other attributes that need to belong with it.

Its going to **group by** at the most granular data point. Since you are only summing or counting one column you will need all other attributes with it in the group by statement.